# Разница между File.getPath(), File.getAbsolutePath() и File.getCanonicalPath()

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Объясните, пожалуйста принципиальную разницу между этими тремя методами:

- `File.getPath()`
- `File.getAbsolutePath()`
- `File.getCanonicalPath()`

Каждый из них возвращает разные пути. Разница между `File.getPath()` и другими двумя мне в целом понятна, а вот что касается `File.getAbsolutePath()` и `File.getCanonicalPath()` чет вообще не могу понять.

Ну и круто будет если приведете несколько реальных примеров использования каждой из них (Лучше если в контексте Android).

Вот я взял в приложении написал маленький тестик для каждого метода и вижу следующее:

```
path = /data/user/0/com.example.testapplication/files
absolutePath = /data/user/0/com.example.testapplication/files 
canonicalPath = /data/data/com.example.testapplication/files
```

Из него мне непонятно почему `user/0/` заменился на `data/`

Comment: `File.getCanonicalPath()` даёт реальный путь файла в ФС - если, к примеру, в изначальном пути есть линк, то он будет заменён на настоящий путь. Статейка по теме: https://www.codeflow.site/ru/article/java-path, написана, правда, коряво (или переведена)

Comment: Значит `user/0/` - это линк, который указывает на `data/`

Comment: @woesss, все пути реальные :), все-таки слово "канонический" или "нормализованный" мне кажется лучше подходит. В остальном все верно. Все это, к слову, написано в Java Doc.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, "нормализованный" - типа приведённый к норме, а к какой норме??? "канонический" - вообще не понятно что означает. Под "реальным" я имею ввиду настоящий, реально-существующий путь к файлу.

Comment: Канонический -- значит по канонам ОС. Любой путь, по которому можно файл открыть есть реальный, но не каждый канонический.

Comment: @woesss, из статьи по вашей ссылке: "Стоит отметить, что один файл в файловой системе может иметь бесконечное количество абсолютных путей, поскольку существует бесконечное число способов использования сокращенных представлений. Однако канонический путь всегда будет уникальным , поскольку все такие представления разрешены." И все эти пути вполне себе реальны.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, как раз таки не реальны, а виртуальны - по ним мы можем получить файл, но их нет в таблице файлов на носителе, они программно преобразуются в реальный путь и уже по нему мы получаем файл с диска.